# Sum array values of a column within each column of an array with 3 levels

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, transpose, array-sum

I'm trying to use `array_sum()` on columns within columns of a multidimensional array.

For eg: I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array = [
    [['value' => 1100], ['value' => 1000], ['value' => 3000]],
    [['value' => 1200], ['value' => 2000], ['value' => 2000]],
    [['value' => 1300], ['value' => 4000], ['value' => 1000]],
];
```

I tried with:

```
$arr = [];
foreach($array as $point){
   $arr[] = array_sum(array_column($array, $point[0]['value']));
}
print_r($arr);
```

but I'm expecting this output:

`[['value' => 3600], ['value' => 7000], ['value' => 6000]]`

Or more simply: `[3600,  7000, 6000]`

Tested here: https://onecompiler.com/php/3y3mxqky9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum your columns doing like this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $point){
  $arr[] = array_sum(array_column( array_column($array,$key),'value'));
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Nice. Just small fix https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/e2a83ea857a2a1203f88ebca2e71ee71/

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to have the sum vertically and not horizontally, the array_column style you used won't work. You can simply achieve this with 2 nested loops like below:

```
<?php

$arr = [];
foreach($array as $point){
   foreach($point as $k => $v){
      $arr[$k] = ($arr[$k] ?? 0) + $v['value'];
   }
}
print_r($arr);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3y3mzyscq)

Answer (score 0):

Transpose your input array, then isolate and sum the `value` column of data.

The variadic offering of `$array` to `array_map()` is the transposing part.

In other words, `array_map(fn(...$col) => $col, ...$array)` converts rows of data into columns of data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0eqvj))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn(...$col) => array_sum(array_column($col, 'value')),
        ...$array
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 3600,
  1 => 7000,
  2 => 6000,
)
```